# jwplayer captions - close by default

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I don't want the caption to show on startup.

I added this:

```
tracks: [{
   file : 'subtitles/file.vtt', 
   kind: 'captions',
   "default" : false
}],
captions: {
   color: '#fff',
   fontSize: 20,
   backgroundColor: '#006666',
   kind: 'captions'
},
```

This doesn't work. I also tried without `'default': false` (the default is off)

Answer (score 2):

The "kind" parameter belongs in the tracks block, not in the captions block. Nevertheless, I have the same problem. Whether setting "default" to false or omitting the parameter, the captions are on when the player starts up. You can fix it by adding

```
playerInstance.setCurrentCaptions(0);
```

after the setup. In some of my configurations this prevented the player from obeying a pause command (by Javascript), so I had to do this:

```
var s = 0;
playerInstance.onPlay(function() {
    if(s==0){
    playerInstance.setCurrentCaptions(0);
    s=1;
   }
});
```

The s variable makes sure that the captions are not turned off on subsequent pause/play actions in case the user turns them on. I assume you are using jwplayer version 7. My captions are .srt, by the way.